# .less not working with Angular ng-class

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, less

I am not able to use my class in .less file via ng-class directive.

I have the following code in body section

```
<li  ng-repeat="menuButton in topMenuData"><a href="{{menuButton.link}}"  ng-    class="{testclass:menuButton.id == {{menuData.top_menu_active}}}"><span >{{menuButton.buttonTitle}}</span></a></li>
```

if my class file is in a  .less it does not work , whereas if it's in a .css file it works fine.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Are you compiling your less files into a css file?  You can't use a less file in the browser.  Its a DSL for compiling to css

Comment: less is just a pre compiler for css. You need to ultimately include the generated css

Comment: Thanks for the info... i did not know anything about less got it compiled to css